# Efficient subseting data with repeated identities in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Say I have the following data and apply the first filter

```
A <- (5:24)
B <- (10:29)
data <- data.frame(A,B)
data$C <- rep(1:((length(A)/2)))
data2 <- subset( data, B < 26)
```

Now I want to further reduce the data, so that only the cases where the repeated `C` values remain. I have used the following code:

```
data3 <- subset(data2, (summary(as.factor(C))) == 2)
```

Is it possible to use `pmatch()` or another efficient manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

- You can try `duplicated`:

  ```
  subset(data2, duplicated(C) | duplicated(C, fromLast = TRUE))
  ```
- Alternatively, you can use `table` and `%in%`:

  ```
  idx <- table(data2$C) > 1
  subset(data2, C %in% names(idx)[idx])
  ```
- A solution with `dplyr`:

  ```
  library(dplyr)
  data2 %>%
    group_by(C) %>%
    filter(n() > 1)
  ```
- A solution with `data.table` (proposed by @akrun):

  ```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(data2)[data2[,.N>1, C]$V1]
  ```